# ASP.NET Web API overloads/params

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, overloading, variadic-functions

The **tl;dr** version is: Can I emulate [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)/overloading for Web API methods without having to implement a custom [IHttpActionSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.ihttpactionselector(v=vs.118).aspx)?

---

#### Params

I was surprised to find that `params` isn't supported in Web API methods (and have since [opened an issue in probably the wrong place](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/49))

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] params Int32[] values) {
    // ...
}
```

`POST`-ing a payload of `[1,2,3]` works as expected, but simply `4` results in `values` being `null`.

#### Overloading

So I decided to try method overloading instead. That, however, doesn't work either.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] Int32 value) {
    return this.Test(new[] { value });
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] Int32[] values) {
    // ...
}
```

Regardless of the payload this (expectedly, I suppose) throws:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: ...

#### Conclusion

It looks like I'll have to try my hand at implementing a custom [IHttpActionSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.ihttpactionselector(v=vs.118).aspx), but I'm wondering if there's any magic I've missed that I could use instead?

Comment: This is a model binding issue. you can create a custom model binder. leave the array and have the binder add any single body to an array for that action

Comment: @Nkosi I didn't think of using a model binder, I'll have to look into this; please feel free to post this as an answer, with a bit more detail if possible. I'll let the question sit for a bit still, to gather more attention, but I'll accept if I can get a working implementation with a model binder.

Comment: Provided an example specific to you scenario but there is room for improvement/expansion on the original solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I emulate params/overloading for Web API methods without having to
>   implement a custom `IHttpActionSelector`?

**YES**

---

This is a binding issue related to the model.

Referencing [HttpParameterBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#httpparameterbinding)

The following binder and attribute was created.

```
public class ParamsAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute {
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter) {
        //Check to make sure that it is a params array
        if (parameter.ParameterType.IsArray &&
            parameter.GetCustomAttributes<ParamArrayAttribute>().Count() > 0) {
            return new ParamsParameterBinding(parameter);
        }
        return parameter.BindAsError("invalid params binding");
    }
}

public class ParamsParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding {

    public ParamsParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor)
        : base(descriptor) {

    }

    public override async Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var descriptor = this.Descriptor;
        var paramName = descriptor.ParameterName;
        var arrayType = descriptor.ParameterType;
        var elementType = arrayType.GetElementType();
        try {
            //can it be converted to array
            var obj = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync(arrayType);
            actionContext.ActionArguments[paramName] = obj;
            return;
        } catch { }
        try {
            //Check if single and wrap in array
            var obj = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync(elementType);
            var array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, 1);
            array.SetValue(obj, 0);
            actionContext.ActionArguments[paramName] = array;
            return;
        } catch { }
    }
}
```

This allowed for the following to accept both single and multiple values posted in the body of the request.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([Params] params Int32[] values) {
    // ...
}
```

`POST`-ing a payload of `[1,2,3]` will work as expected, also simply with 4 will result in `values` being `[4]`.

The binder now respects the `params` modifier, thus enabling endpoints to accept one-or-many of a given parameter. It will also work for non-primitive objects

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Customers")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([Params] params Customer[] customers) {
    // do important stuff
}
```

This could be improved further to work with any collection as a parameter to accept single or multiple values, not just `params`.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you, I'll give it a shot first thing when I'm back at my desk shortly :-)

Comment: @Dan did you get a chance to confirm that this is the answer?

Comment: Funny enough, doing it literally now; just moved the relevant ticket to "In Progress" ;-)

Comment: @Dan cool. I ran it through some integration tests and everything seemed in order. Was just wondering how it worked in your environment. Already looking at ways to incorporate it into some of my current projects. This was a good question.

Comment: So, it doesn't appear to work, because any calls to `ReadAsAsync` after the first fail; the underlying stream position is already moved. I'm trying to patch it with a single call to `ReadAsStreamAsync`, and subsequent calls to parse the stream.

Comment: @Dan, I tested it with an in-memory server for the single parameter which meant that it had to fail the first check yet it still worked when the second call to `ReadAsAsync` was made.

Comment: Yea I followed the logic there; seemed pretty straight forward; then it failed and I was surprised and sad, lol. I'll work out the single call to `ReadAsStreamAsync`, just working on the formatter selection.

Comment: @Dan you can do a read as string and then do the JasonConvert manually in the two try/catch. That way only once call to the stream is needed. I was hoping the ReadAsAsync would work as it would use the formatters and settings of the framework.

Comment: @Dan I've been giggling at how well this worked in all my tests. and having fun making refactors to see what other neat things I can do with it. Sad to hear how it is not working on your end. I find that very curious. Keep me posted. I am too invested in this now. :)

Comment: Heading home from work, so I'll give it another shot when I get there. The formatters is the part I'm getting caught on; I don't want to use `JsonConvert` and ignore XML (or other media types). So I'm just trying to cleanly pull in and use the configured formatters so different media types are still supported.